# why don't we need suffix on long in java?

Tags: java

While writing some code I noticed that long(primitive) data type does not need to have the suffix l or L. My code compiles and run fine with this. Can anyone explain the logic Behind this ?? Thanks in advance..

```
long l=435; //Complies and Run fine
```

Comment: Try it with a really long number...

Answer (score 11):

When you do:

```
long l=435;
```

The compiler considers it as an `int`, and then, since the data type you have given is a `long`, so it does **automatic conversion** to `long` data type. So you don't need a suffix.

However, if you try it with a really long number, like:

```
long l = 9999999999;
```

The compiler will throw an error (*integer number too large*). Because, it will try to consider it as an `int`, but it is too big to be an `int`. So, here, you need a suffix. If you do:

```
long l = 9999999999L;
```

Then it will compile.
Simply, a suffix is needed for a number which can only fit in a `long` data type.

Answer (score 2):

Because an int type can automatically be converted to long.

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning a really bug number, like `long l = 0xFFFFFFFFF;`.

When you initialize a literal like 0xFFFFFFFFF, if there is no suffix and the variable is an integral type(int, long, etc), the value is assumed to be an `int`. And, an `int` can hold 32 bits, not 36 bits (9 x `0xF` = 9 x `'1111'`) like you will be trying if you type `long l = 0xFFFFFFFFF;`. So, you have to use a `long` that has a capacity of 64 bits. Appending 'L' or 'l' to the end of the value, like 0xFFFFFFFFFL, should take care of the compiler error. [[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10)]

In general, since the type conversion to long will happen anyway, it is a good idea to be explicit about that `L`.